# Same fdisk identifier on multiple USB sticks

Tags: usb-drive, fdisk

I'm trying to understand if I'm creating chaos in my system with two USB sticks that were accidentally dd'd to have the exact same contents, including `fdisk` identifier when inspected with:

`sudo fdisk -l | grep Disk identifier:`

Each of the partitions, e.g. /dev/sdd1, /dev/sdd2, also have UUIDs that match the other stick, e.g. /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdc2.

Environment: Ubuntu Server, 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: As long as you do not plug them in at same time, it should be ok. Just as a image backup. But you cannot have duplicate UUIDs. You may get data copied to one drive one time and to the other next time. And they may then not always be sdc & sdd in same order.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: On my computer things get confused when multiple cloned devices with the same UUID get plugged in. I have had some success using the option in GParted to generate new UUID's